# Disable registration on commerce checkout

Tags: commerce

According to https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/checkout/allow-register-at-checkout the 'Login or continue as guest' checkout pane should have an option 'Allow registration'. In my environment with the latest commerce 2.12 however I can't find this option. Why is this option not shown?

I don't want to allow registrations on my site and only allow guest checkout. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's definitely still there on 2.12.
It's only shown when "Allow guest checkout" is disabled (if you allow guest checkout, we only offer registration at the end of checkout, via the "Guest registration after checkout" pane which you can disable).

Comment: yes, you are right. But what I wanted to do doesn't work. I only want to have a guest checkout. No login, no new account registration possibility. How can I do this?

Comment: Just disable both panes (""Login or continue as guest" and "Guest registration after checkout")

Comment: Thank you! So easy actually. But this should be better docuemented, as it seems that this pane is required to '... continue as guest'. I have not thought about disabling it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Bojan's comments, leave "Allow guest checkout" checked and disable the "Guest registration after checkout" pane. We may need to update the documentation a little, but doing these things and then configuring your general Drupal settings to deny user account registration will leave you with a site that no one can ever register against and anonymous users can still checkout on.

(The fact that you don't see the checkbox to "Allow registration" in the "Login or continue as guest" checkout pane configuration is irrelevant, because it's disabled by default. You don't need access to it in order to disable the ability for guests to register prior to checkout.)

If you don't need this intermediate step at all, you can simply disable the checkout pane and the page will be skipped for all customers.

Comment: The returning customer login is still shown. How can I also remove this one?

Comment: Ahh, can you not just disable that initial checkout pane to skip that page entirely if that's what you want?

Comment: yes, that works. It was not clear to me that when disabling this pane the guest checkout is still possible as the pane is labeled 'Login or continue as guest'

Comment: Cool, I'll update my answer, and if you can mark it as accepted, that'd be great! : )